# Show extra field in category view

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

i'm using K2 component to show some article in category view. I'd like to show the extra fields in the category view. They are visible in single article but not in category view. Is ti possible?
Thanks

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)